# WireGuard VPN server on AWS EC2 Speed drops 1/10 after connection

Tags: networking, vpn, performance, amazon-web-services, wireguard

I am trying to set up a WireGuard VPN server on AWS EC2 instance. Since I am on free tier I could only use `t2.micro` instances. I've checked the network bandwidth for instances on their documentation it stated as `low-moderate`. I have a `100mbps` connection but upon connection I get only `10mbps`. I am in India and the region I choose was Canada Central. Is that the maximum performance I could get or can I do anything to improve performance? Is there any benchmark stats performed or how could I perform one?

Comment: Wireguard configs can be tuned for better performance, much the same as OpenVPN requires tuning to provide max throughput - I'd imagine at least the Wireguard server config would need to be included within a code box _(please anonymize it first, removing the keys, port, etc.)_. I'm more familiar with OpenVPN, and with it, usually when throughput is an issue with a self-hosted VPN it's due to an incorrect encryption setting being set way too high, using an inefficient cipher.